# Dynamic SVG Text not running in Firefox

Tags: firefox, svg

I will put some Text on a path via SVG. The text can be inserted on the website via an input (text) element.
After I create the SVG in JQuery I put it into a DIV.
In IE and Chrome it works, meaning the text is shown correctly on the path.
But in Firefox it is shown out of the box and not correctly on the path.

```
<svg id="svgtext_o" height="100%" width="100%" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <defs> <path id="textpfadtext_o" d="m 20,93 a 56,84 0 0 1 112,0">
   </defs>
   <desc>SVG Gruest fuer die Darstellung!</desc>
   <g>
     <text id="texttext_o" transform="" letter-spacing="60px">
       <textPath style="fill:none;stroke:#B3B3B3;stroke-width:0.833;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1" xlink:href="#textpfadtext_o"> <tspan id="tspantext_o" class="BankGothic" fontsize="10" fill="#B3B3B3" stroke="#B3B3B3">jjjj</tspan>
       </textPath>
     </text>
   </g>
</svg>
```

Whats wrong? Any suggestions?

The strange thing is, if ein copy that to an extra file and open this file via Firefox.
Then it will shown the SVG correctly!?! Why not in the Div?

Here is the requested JQuery code:

```
function setSVG(kopf_text_path, kopf_text_svg_max_length, fontselect, fontsizeselect, txtInput, element_sequel, transform_text) {
var svg_header = "<svg id='svg_" + element_sequel +"' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'><title>SVG Head Text</title><desc>SVG Gruest fuer die Darstellung von Ringkopftexten!</desc>";
var sInnerHTML = '<path id="textpfad_" + element_sequel +" d="' + kopf_text_path + '" fill="none" /> <text textLength="' + kopf_text_svg_max_length + '" lengthAdjust="spacing" ' + ' transform="' + transform_text + '" ><textPath xlink:href="#textpfad" ><tspan class="' + $(fontselect + ' option:selected').val() + '" style="stroke:#B3B3B3; fill:#B3B3B3; font-size:' + $(fontsizeselect + ' option:selected').val() + 'px">' + $(txtInput).val() + '</tspan></textPath></text>';
$(".div_head_" + element_sequel).empty().append(svg_header + sInnerHTML + "</svg>");
```

};
This is executed every time, if someone press a key in a input-textbox.

Thx

Comment: You are creating the output in the wrong namespace but as you haven't shown that code it's hard to comment in more detail.

Comment: This is in an OpenCart project. I'm not sure what namespace is used. Which namespace I should use?

Comment: Is the xmlns attribute in the SVG-tag wrong or should it define somewhere else?

Comment: No that's right. The bug is in some code you've not shown us.

Comment: Should I print here the hole Code up to the html-tag? It's a lot of Code!

Comment: Have edit the code. Hope that's better for analysis.

Comment: No, you're still not showing us the JQuery javascript code.

Comment: thx for the bear with me. I have added the task with the JQuery code.